# pods in different workers(nodes) is not reachable via macvlan

Tags: kubernetes, macvlan

I have a kubernetes cluster which has 1 master and 2 workers, and deployed via kubeadm.
For networking, I use multus and create two cni, the default is calico and another is [macvlan](https://github.com/intel/multus-cni/blob/master/doc/quickstart.md).

After I created 3 pods, they are deployed to 2 workers, and the pods in the same worker are pingable, but the pods in different workers ARE'T pingable.

How could I check?
Thanks very much!

Comment: Are they created in the same namespace ?

Comment: yes, the same namespace.

Comment: Find some strange. the PODs on different workers have the same ip address.
that's to say, macvlan will assign ip address per worker range, not the cluster range.

Comment: cat mybusybox.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: mybusybox
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    app: mybusybox
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        k8s.v1.cni.cncf.io/networks: macvlan-conf
      labels:
        app: mybusybox
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mybusybox
        image: busybox
        command: ["/bin/sh"]
        args: ["-c", "sleep 10000000000"]

Comment: Hi @Andy, I think it would be easier to find help if you provided some configuration samples you use. I see you added something in the comment above, but it's hardly readable. Please edit your question and use code block to preserve indentation of the YAML format. Please provide configuration of the Multus, Calico and macvlan. Also please specify what IP addresses were assigned to which Pods.